# How to differentiate between elements that contain the same text Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to take user input in order to navigate through a website. I'm trying to identify elements in the webpage based on the users input, however sometimes the string the user inputs will match multiple elements and therefore I'll click on the wrong one.

```
search = input("Enter something to search for")
elem = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(f'//span[text()="{search}"]')
```

Are there any tips to identify elements in a dynamic enviroment? I was thinking perhaps I could identify the element by two criteria - such as it matching the text (as above), but also by an attribute the other two elements don't have?

As it's dynamic there aren't many set attributes that I can base the search off (I won't know the class name upfront, or the id). The only thing I can think of to add on top of the string matching is the text of the outer class it will be in, as this is consistent across all the searches I'll conduct but I'm not sure if this is possible?

Any tips in identifying elements in a dynamic enviroment are appreciated.

The xpaths for the three elements with exactly the same text are:

```
/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/li/button/span/ul/li/span[2]/span
/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/li[1]/a/span/ul/li[1]/span/span
/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/li[2]/a/span/ul/li[1]/span[1]/span
```

An example of one of the elements (they all look like this):

```
<span class="ccl-19882374e640f487 ccl-1daa0367dee37c3b">TEXT</span>
```

And an h4 "title" tag, that sits above some of the matching elements:

```
<h4 class="ccl-2a4b5924e2237093 ccl-21bead492ce4ada2 ccl-706ed5a06ead17d8 ccl-2b95b58eee016846">Categories</h4>
```

Screenshot of the problem below. When you search hotels for "London" you are given a list of multiple elements under a **Locations** heading and multiple elements under a **Properties** heading. I'd like to click the first element that appears under the properties heading. This is just one example and it will vary depending on what place the user searches for so there may not always be a known number of locations/properties returned - there may never be any locations returned!

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Give html code with examples of matching elements. If you want to find by text - css does not support this.

Comment: Can you share the url?

Comment: https://www.ryanair.com/gb/en. I've added a screenshot and description of the exact issue to the original question as I'm not sure how to add an image to a comment

Answer (score 0):

Maybe simply adding if statement will slightly help:

```
search = input("Enter something to search for")
elem = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(f'//span[text()="{search}"]')
if len(elem) > 1:
     elem[0].click() # select the element you want to click from the list
```

If the elements in the list will contain some extra attributes you can filter them in that way:

```
search = input("Enter something to search for")
elem = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(f'//span[text()="{search}"]')
if len(elem) > 1:
     elem.find_element_by_css_selector('type_of_selector[class="some_class"]')
```

Could you provide more details about those elements and we'll think about the solution. Regards!

Comment: There are three elements that all return the exact same text so unfortunately an if statement on the text won't be able to differentiate between them. I've added the xpaths the elements sit in, and an example of what one of the elements looks like, if that helps? One way I can think to differentiate these three elements is that 2 of the 3 sit under an h4 tag with the title "groups" (shown in above question), whereas the other 1 sits under a n h4 tag with the title "categories". I wan't to select the first element under the groups heading, however it keeps retrieving the one under "categories"

Comment: Yes, its because od you call webdriver.find_element method: the first element which meet the restrictions wilk be returned. As I wrote earlier: you have to use webdriver.find_elements method and you'll obtain all elements gathered into a list. Its up to you which element will be selected.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the problem to the initial question, it might help explain it better than I have so far